# Cannot find Object methods on Valuetype class

Tags: c#, .net

Even though ValueType is derived from Object class, why ValueType class doesn't have all of Object methods?

[image: screenshot from Visual Studio]

Comment: Methods listed on your screenshot are all public methods of `Object`, which are missing you think?

Comment: MemberwiseClone, Finalize methods are missing. Are protected methods of a class not accessible on instance of that class?

Comment: Protected means "accessible only inside this class and child classes". You are not "inside" child class of object, so they are not accessible.

Comment: That answers my questions. Thank you Evk.